# How to refresh individual tiles in openlayers?

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to build an app which has tiles changing over time. So Far I was able to refresh just the entire tile source. However whenever you refresh it there is a short blink of the entire picture - the picture is deleted and redraw again. However, if the tiles are loading only part of image where the new tile is loaded is redrawn. I would like to get similar behaviour

```
var Source=new ol.source.OSM({
                url: 'http://localhost:900/{z}-{x}-{y}.png',
                attributions:[],
                wrapX: false    ,
                tileLoadFunction:function(imageTile, src) {var mr = Math.random();    imageTile.getImage().src = src+'?t='+mr;}
            });
```

plus refreshing:

```
Source.tileCache.expireCache({});
            Source.tileCache.clear();
            Source.refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not possible to change the way refresh works without rewriting part of OpenLayers but if you maintain an update timestamp for each tile instead of adding a random value OpenLayers will use browser cache when there is no update required instead of reloading every tile from the server, making a faster refresh so the flicker should be less noticeable.  As it will be indexed by tile coordinates it will need to be added in the tileUrlFunction instead of the tileLoadFunction.  The OSM constructor doesn't support tileUrlFunction, but XYZ can be used instead.

```
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var updateTimes = {};

var source = new ol.source.XYZ({
    attributions:[],
    wrapX: false,
    tileUrlFunction: function(tileCoord) {
        var z = tileCoord[0];
        var x = tileCoord[1];
        var y = -tileCoord[2]-1;
        var timestamp = updateTimes[ z + '_' + x + '_' y ] || startTime;
        return 'http://localhost:900/' + z + '-' + x + '-' + y + '.png?t=' + timestamp;
    }
});

function refresh(x, y, z) {
  updateTimes[ z + '_' + x + '_' y ] = new Date().getTime();
  source.refresh();
}
```

You might get a further improvement by preloading the new tile to populate the browser cache before refreshing

```
function refresh(x, y, z) {
  updateTimes[ z + '_' + x + '_' y ] = new Date().getTime();
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.onload = function() {
      img.remove();
      source.refresh();
  };
  img.src = 'http://localhost:900/' + z + '-' + x + '-' + y + '.png?t=' + updateTimes[ z + '_' + x + '_' y ];
}
```

Comment: Thank for the answer. This will really help to not load huge amount data from the server. However, the flicker is still there. Is there any other possibility than source.refresh() to update the image?

Comment: I don't know of a way without using refresh().  The flicker was minimal when I have tested toggling individual tiles between OSM and OpenTopoMap, even with a timestamp, but with a slower server response even loading one new tile might well cause a noticeable delay.  Maybe a dummy load of the image to populate the browser cache before refreshing would improve things.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it - you cant refresh entire source, but just remove the tile from the cache:

```
function RefreshIndividual(z,x, y) {
            var index= z+'-'+x+'-'+y;
            var index2= z+'/'+x+'/'+(-y-1);
            updateTimes[index] = new Date().getTime();
            console.log(index,'t'+updateTimes[index]);
            Source.tileCache.remove(index2);
            Source.changed();

        }
```

Comment: That seems to work with OpenLayers 5, but with v4.6.5 source.tileCache can only be accessed using the debug build  Is it included in the API documentation yet?